# Getting "Current Sitecore database cannot be established" using Sitecore Powershell Extensions

Tags: powershell-extensions

I'm trying to get my feet wet in Sitecore Powershell.
I need to list renderings on a list of items. Some of the script works, like getting the items and outputting the name, but when calling `Get-Rendering` or `Get-LayoutDevice` i always get the error:

```
Current Sitecore database cannot be established, current location is not within a Sitecore content tree.
```

Google offers no help. What am I doing wrong? The script I am buildling on currently looks like this:

```powershell
$pages = get-item master:/content/MySite/articles | get-childitem -Recurse | where-object { $_.TemplateName -match "Article" }
$device = Get-LayoutDevice -Default

foreach($page in $pages){
    write-host $page.name
    Get-Rendering -Item $page -Device $device    
}
```

Comment: That script seems to work fine on a fresh Sitecore 8.2.

Are you logged in as admin? What version of Sitecore & Powershell are you running?

Comment: Using Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 151207) and Powershell 4.1

Comment: Cool - are you running it in the Powershell console? If so - what's before the cursor? (Should be something like "PS master:\>")

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SPE loses Sitecore context if `/sitecore/content/home` item is not present and falls back to Windows context.

To force it to use the master database set the location at the top of your script:

```powershell
Set-Location master:
```

You can also set the context from the ISE window from the ribbon:

[image: ISE Set Context]

This was [raised as an issue](https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues/729) on Github and has been fixed in SPE 4.2 so that the context falls back to `/sitecore/content` instead.