# SPE report fails to run in Reporting Tools; runs successfully in the ISE

Tags: powershell-extensions

I've created multiple custom reports for content managers. They all run as expected in the Sitecore Powershell ISE. 
When I save them in Reporting Tools and attempt to run I am getting errors. 
The first error was due to the relative -Path so I added the master: prefix and that fixed it.
The error I'm stuck on is "Get-ItemTemplate : Current Sitecore database cannot be established, current location is not within a Sitecore content tree"

Here is the relevant part of the report script. It fails on the last line:

```
$path = $root.Paths.FullPath
$pathtouse = "master:" + $path
#Get Items
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path $pathtouse -Recurse
#For each item check templates
foreach($item in $items){
    $template = Get-ItemTemplate -ID $item.ID
}
```

Comment: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2574/getting-current-sitecore-database-cannot-be-established-using-sitecore-powersh
have you tried this?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In my case I'm already on SPE 5.x and location is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you need to add the `-Path` parameter when using `-ID` or instead just use `-Item $item`. The database is not known when calling the `Get-ItemTemplate` command.

https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/common/get-itemtemplate

```
Get-ItemTemplate -Item $item
```

Comment: You are right on with the suggestion. Appreciate the quick help.
Get-Template -Item $item did the trick.